# Bootstrap Navigation responsive issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

this is my nav http://www.noor-azmi.com/element/nav.html

The problem is when i minimize the browser, you can see that the nav down goes down before it changes to the mobile nav icon

!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7kUV.jpg)

I do not want the nav to go down.

2nd issue is i do not want the green top border on top of the text anymore when it become the mobile navi.

!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KMOQ.jpg)

This is the CSS for my Navbar

```
 .new-nav li a {
                display: block;
                padding: 0 80px;
                padding-top: 20px;
                border-top: 5px solid #89c765;
                color: #b2b3b6;
            }
```

I tried to change the properties for the mobile nav by using this class

.navbar-toggle a but does not change.

Pls help thanks

Answer (score 0):

Issue #1: change this:

```
.navbar li a {
  padding:0 30px;
}
```

to this:

```
.navbar li a {
  padding:0 24px;
}
```

Issue #2: add this code:

```
@media (max-width:767px){
    .navbar a {
        border:none;
    }
}
```